# SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server using phpmailer 6.0 in localhost XAMPP

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I'm trying to send mail using phpmailer 6.0. I updated my php version and I made my mail "verify less secure apps " because I'm using gmail.

I get an error like this:

> 2017-12-09 23:30:09 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0)
>   SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
>   Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

I'm using sample code from the readme file.

```
<?php 
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'PHPMailer-master/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer-master/src/SMTP.php';
require 'PHPMailer-master/src/Exception.php';

$mail =  new PHPMailer(true);                     
try {

$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                 
$mail->isSMTP();                                      
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               
$mail->Username = 'username@gmail.com';                 
$mail->Password = 'password';                           
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            
$mail->Port = 465;                                    
$mail->setFrom('username@gmail.com');
$mail->addAddress('username@gmail.com');     

$mail->isHTML(true);                                  
$mail->Subject = 'hello';
$mail->Body    = 'dasdasd';
$mail->AltBody = 'dasdasd';

$mail->send();
echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
 ?>
```

*note I am not using composer because there isn't any vendor folder when I download the phpmailer.

Comment: comment //$mail->isSMTP(); and then check

Comment: if u comment the $mail->isSMTP the mail function wouldn't be initiate

Comment: Commenting out isSMTP will not solve this. You’re sending from a gmail address so you **must** send through gmail via SMTP. This is probably a TLS issue. Set SMTPDebug =3 to get more connection info, and read what the troubleshooting guide says about that.

Comment: if the problem on the tls i already set this $mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false;